# How do I remove all rows from data frame that equal unique value in seperate data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `df1` that has missing values (`NA`) for different sites. I have identified the largest `NA` gap for each site and now I want to remove those sites from the `df1` data frame, how do I do this efficiently?

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 20))
x <- c("siteID", "Date", "Wtemp")
colnames(df1) <- x
df1$siteID <- c(101,101,101,101,101,
                102,102,102,102,102,
                103,103,103,103,103,
                104,104,104,104,104)
df1$Date <- rep(seq(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-01-05"), by = 1),4)  
df1$Wtemp <- c(10,NA,NA,NA,15,
               20,NA,NA,10,16,
               2,4,6,8,10,
               12,14,16,18,20)

MaxGap_Wtemp <- df1 %>%
  group_by(siteID) %>%
  summarise(MaxGap = with(rle(is.na(Wtemp)),
                          max(0, max(lengths[values]))), .groups = 'drop')

MaxGap_Wtemp$Frac_missing <- round(((MaxGap_Wtemp$MaxGap/5)*100),digits=2)

remove_sites <- MaxGap_Wtemp[MaxGap_Wtemp$Frac_missing > 30,]

zz <- unique(remove_sites$siteID)
```

I can manually remove sites from `df1` by using the following code

```
dat <- df1[!(df1$siteID == 101 |
                df1$siteID == 102),]
View(dat)
```

However, I would like to reference `zz` that has the unique `siteID` for the sites that need to be removed as it would be more efficient for large datasets with long siteID values. I have tried doing this using the code below but the output is not correct (please see output of `dat` for how the output should look).

```
dat2 <- df1[!(df1$siteID == zz),]
```

Any ideas on how I can reference those sites in `zz` to remove all the rows in `df1` that have a `siteID` that is equal to `zz`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `==`, we need `%in%` and negate (`!`) as `==` can work only if the `length` is 1 or same as that of the column to be compared because it is doing elementwise comparison

```
df[!(df1$siteID %in% zz),]
```